# Can't fetch a specific YouTube subscription by ID

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

When using the Google APIs explorer or other tools, I can't seem to fetch a subscription by ID.
For example, you can get the ID of a subscription using the explorer by going here and clicking execute: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix_params=%7B%22channelId%22%3A%22UCacsMRrp9ql-vdgpn0zUIdQ%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A1%7D&apix=true

If you try to fetch the subscription using this ID, it returns no results with no error. You can do this here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22id%22%3A%5B%22d2SMBqJ86w1w7l0zi030jugfSr0MRBRwJ08thmzl2H4%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A1%7D

It should definitely return exactly 1 result. This must be a bug with the YouTube Data API, correct? And if so, how would I go about reporting this?

Comment: Do file a bug report to Google through its [own issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @stvar done! We'll see what Google does about it. Should I go ahead and make that the answer?

Comment: Of course, that's a good SO practice: later, other SO users may find that answer (and the link to the official Google staff answer) be useful. Until you've got the official answer, suffices to post  a comment containing the link to that bug report of yours.

Comment: The bug report can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181152600).